# MAVProxy installed by Python can't find required modules

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I installed droneapi in the same manner given in the tutorial. However, it's missing all of the important modules that come with MAVProxy, such as console, wx, etc.

Was it supposed to install these modules, or should I move them over from MAVProxy itself instead?

Note: Windows 8 64-bit platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in a rare spark of intuition I discovered the answer. The modules required by Dronekit Python can be installed in the following ways:

Console- type "pip install console" into the WinPython cmd prompt 
WX- http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython 
OpenCV- Download and install [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.11/) version 2.4, then copy/paste the file cv2.pyd from OpenCV\build\python\2.7\x64\ to \python-2.7.6.amd64\Lib\site-packages.

At this point it should load all required modules, although it will throw a few exceptions which aren't important.

As always, 3DR documentation is incomplete. One would think that $800 million dollar profits would mean that they could hire more than 5 programmers for their new platform...

Answer (score 1):

I apologize that you had to investigate the issue without guidance. Publishing our Windows installer was not well prioritized, and it looks like that choice cost you several hours.

Here is what we will soon to address DroneKit Python installation on Windows:

- A dedicated Windows installer generator lives at `windows/droneapiWinBuild.bat`. This generates a program `Output\DroneKitsetup-1.x.x.exe` which can be used to install all dependencies.
- Yesterday we began testing the installer on Windows on every commit. https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/pull/236
- We will now publish the binaries generated by that test and document them in the Windows installation process. https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/issues/164

Thanks for publishing your solution publicly. Hopefully we can address issues like these before they come up in the future.

Tim, DroneKit Engineer

Comment: In that case, I should probably mention that to run  the simulator with MAVProxy.py I had to change line 427 of sim_vehicle.sh to • cygstart -w "/cygdrive/c/Users/<Your Username>/Desktop/WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4/python-2.7.6.amd64/Dronekit/Scripts/mavproxy.py" $options --cmd="$extra_cmd" $*

Comment: Also using your installer requires that you download Inno Setup 5. Perhaps you should just fix the documentation or something crazy like that.

Comment: That's fair, and thank you for the update about running cygwin. We are now posting the resulting [installers for Windows](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/issues/164#issuecomment-126136345) which won't require InnoSetup (only generating the installer does). Documenting running the MAVProxy.exe installer followed by the Dronekit.exe installer is being added shortly.

We also intend to provide a cleaner alternative to sim_vehicle.sh via https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-sitl. Thanks for your patience and persistence while we pull this together.

Comment: The installer you linked works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: FYI The changes for the DroneKit-Python windows installer are now in a push request https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/pull/268. The old instructions are still necessary for contributors - I have put in the information on OpenCV etc in that section.

Comment: Where do you want me to address issues with the DroneKit.io guide? I keep finding problems where it doesn't match up with the code itself.

Comment: It's still missing all of the libraries when I run pip install.